# No "Additional Compiler Options" in Build > Compiling pane of Netbeans 11.2

Tags: java, netbeans, java-13

I am using Netbeans 11.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 as snap package. Try to enable `--enable-preview` in a Maven project as described in the [documentation](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/index.html):

[image]

I do not see "Additional Compiler Options" in my UI, see below

[image]

The referenced issue is merged, so what is wrong here?

Note that building and running the application (using preview features) via Maven from inside Netbeans, is just working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The referenced issue is merged, so what is wrong here?

While the referenced issue is merged, that doesn't necessarily mean that the fix has been included in NetBeans 11.2, and apparently it hasn't.

If you look at the associated Jira Bug Report, "[NETBEANS-2450 javac compiler option --enable-preview doesn't take effect for maven projects](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2450)", the fix will be applied in NetBeans 12.0.

Comment: I feel ashamed :( You are right, did not read the information well enough